# Null Exception Error and New to OOP

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception

I am working on a GoFish game in java in my take turn method I wrote I receive a Null Exception Error, and I know that means I have a null object.

When going through my code I can not figure out why I am getting this. When I ask the user for number of player it creates that number. SO why would I get a null error for this

```
if((P.cardsInHand[P.getnumCardsInHand()].getRank()) == rank){
                    return P;
                }


private Player[] numPlayers;
int playerName;
int requestedcard;
public void numPlayers(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many players want to play");
        numPlayer = input.nextInt();

        if((numPlayer < 2) || (numPlayer > 6)){
            System.out.println("How many players want to play");
            numPlayer = input.nextInt();
        }
        numPlayers = new Player[numPlayer];

        for (int i = 0; i <  numPlayer; i++){

            System.out.println("Player Number(Start with 0)");
            playerName = input.nextInt();
            numPlayers[i] = new Player(playerName);
        }
        requestedPlayer = numPlayers[0];
    }

     public Player taketurn(Player P){
         previousPlayer = P;
         System.out.println(P);
        //set up scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //declare variables
        int player;
        int rank;
        int numMatches = 0;
        System.out.println("Player " + previousPlayer.getnumplayerNumber() + " turn");
        //Player P ask what player cars it want to sk for
        System.out.println("what Player Do you want to ask");
        player = input.nextInt();
        if(player > numPlayer){
            System.out.println("what Player Do you want to ask");
            player = input.nextInt();
        }
        //data type of Player is set to the player that Play P requested
        requestedPlayer = numPlayers[player];
        //request card
        System.out.println("What rank do you want(2-10 = the corresponding number rank on the card, 11 = jack, 12 = queen, 13 = king, 14 = ace)");
        rank = input.nextInt();


        for(int i = 1; i < (requestedPlayer.getnumCardsInHand()); i++){
            if((requestedPlayer.cardsInHand[i].getRank()) == rank){
                // if requested rank == to the player that was aksed for the card
                //the card will be transfered and removed from hand
                requestedPlayer.cardsInHand[i].test1();
                System.out.println("Card of rank " + rank + " are being transfered");
                //requestedPlayer.cardsInHand[i].test();
                for(int j = 1; j < (requestedPlayer.getnumCardsInHand()); j++){
                    P.transfercard(i, requestedPlayer);
                    requestedPlayer.removeCard(i);
                }


                P.findBooks();
                return P;
            }else{
                //place draw in paremters
                System.out.println("Go Fish");
                P.addCard(d.draw());
                if((P.cardsInHand[P.getnumCardsInHand()].getRank()) == rank){
                    return P;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Requested Players turn");
                    return (requestedPlayer);
                }
            }
        }  
        return requestedPlayer;
    }
```

Comment: Please more information. Like the line where the exception occurs.

Comment: It happens at this point if((P.cardsInHand[P.getnumCardsInHand()].getRank()) == rank){
                    return P;
                }                                                                It is line 88 in the program I am using to write the code. Can you attach documents it might be easier to explain if i could attach the player class too.

Comment: then either `P` is null or `P.cardsInHand[P.getnumCardsInHand()]` returned null.  ..or `P.getnumCardsInHand()` returned null

Comment: When the exception is thrown, what is the value of `P.getnumCardsInHand()`?  How many elements are in `P.cardsInHand[]`?

Comment: Which method call taketurn method ??

Comment: Use breakpoints to view variables during execution.  You should be able to identify exactly what the issue is then.

Comment: The program that I used to write this program does not have break points ability. The P.cardsInHand holds 25 items but when the game starts only the first five 5 spaces are filled with card objects, and the other 20 is space for more card to be added during the game.

Comment: The reference P of class Player in the parameter of method taketurn is null

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: How is the parameter null? When I call it with requestedPlayer in the numPlayer method it takes the value of the first player which has been initialized.

Comment: It's almost certain that `P.cardsInHand[nnn]` is `null`, where `nnn` is the array element you're trying to access.  If you said `cardsInHand = new Card[5]` or something, but forgot to set each element to a `Card`, they will all be `null`.  Otherwise, maybe you initialized some of the elements but didn't initialize all of them.

Comment: On the line before you receive a NPE, add statements like `if (P == null) { System.out.println("P is null") }` to quickly determine which object is null, then work backwards.

Comment: What is `getnumCardsInHand()`?  If it's the actual number of cards in a player's hand, please remember that array indexing starts at 0, so if `N` items in your array are used, they will be indexed from 0 to `N-1`, and in that case the `[N]` element will not exist (and might be `null` to mean an unused element).

Comment: @turbo keep in mind that if `P` were null, the exception would have been thrown on the previous line.

Comment: @ajb ah true, I just picked that for ease of writing, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `P.cardsInHand` is an array with 25 elements, but you're only using the first 5, then the elements `P.cardsInHand[0]`, `P.cardsInHand[1]`, ... `P.cardsInHand[4]`, will have values, but `P.cardsInHand[5]` will probably be `null`.  If `getnumCardsInHand()` returns 5, then the array element will be `null`, which will cause the `NullPointerException`.  Use `P.getnumCardsInHand()-1`.

Since arrays in Java (and C and many other languages) are indexed starting at 0, that means that if you want to access the *last* element of the array (or, in your case, the last "used" element), you need to subtract 1 from any value that gives you the number of elements (such as `a.length` for an array, `a.size()` for an `ArrayList`, or in your case `P.getnumCardsInHand()`).

Comment: Thanks it makes more since now.